# Restarting excel serial number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

[image]

I wants to add a auto serial number into my excel sheet which  should restart from 1 automatically as soon as the text in the next column changed. For example I have column of subjects i.e English, Hindi, Persian etc. I have sorted there data a-z now I want serial numbers based on this subjects column   starting from 1 for each group of subject. I tried this

```
=IF(E31="","",(SUBTOTAL(103,$E$2:E31)))
```

but it continued the serial numbers until I filter the data. but I need serial number auto restart on the condition based on subject column. please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this solve your problem: `=IF(D2="","",IF(E2=E1,A1+1,1))` ?

Answer (score 1):

You mention "subjects" but your example does not show that column. Using a simplified sample, I would just do this in cell A2:

```
    =IF(B2=B1,A1+1,1)
```

Drag it down.
[image]